# Euclidean view in curved manifold

Tags: spacetime, curvature, locality

Let's suppose I am an ant who lives in a 2D curved space. Locally the world seems 2d-euclidean to me, but it is not if I consider a large portion of space.

Now let's consider a human being who lives in curved 4d spacetime. Locally the spacetime seems 4d-euclidean --> in fact, the space itself appears 3d-euclidean to us. But if we consider a larger portion of spacetime, then the curvature will inevitably be evident.

However: if I look around me in any moment, the space seems to me 3d euclidean EVERYWHERE, not only locally. I mean, it seems like I can extend my 3d-euclidean-grid forever in space (at least according to my eyes).

How can this be possible if spacetime is curved? Do our eyes give us misleading impressions?

Comment: how would our eyes see light following the curvature of space as not being straight

Comment: @adrian I don't know. But what our eyes see is an euclidean 3d flat space even though it is  not... do you agree?

Comment: My eyes currently tell me that there is no universe beyond my living room.  Should I believe them?

Comment: Maybe read [Kant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQnG0fyEr_w)

Comment: Consider to define the word _Euclidean._ It has different meanings in the litterature. Do you mean _flat?_

Comment: @Qmechanic yes I mean "flat". To our senses the space around us appears flat, even though it is not flat according to Einstein. So do our senses get a wrong impression?

Comment: Consider to reformulate. Right now the title (v1) sounds like you're asking _How to Wick-rotate in curved spacetime?_

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism

Answer (score 0):

You need sensitive instruments/telescopes to see that light does not always follow straight lines, but it is possible - see [Tests of General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity).

In the everyday world, if I want to send an apple from A so that it arrives 1 second later at B 1 metre away, then I have to throw it so that it follows a ballistic trajectory. If I just aim it in a straight line from A to B at a velocity of 1 metre per second then it will fall to the floor. This is actually evidence that our local 4D spacetime is curved by the nearby presence of a large mass (the Earth). But we don't intuitively think of it that way.